# MongoDB - How to search a Document that have two fields with the same key

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document in production that have two fields with the same key, but i don't know the value of these fields, example:

```
{
    "email":"email1@idk.com", 
    "email":"email2@idk.com"
}
```

When i'm trying to copy the collection to another database, it says that one document have a duplicate key. How can i search this document to mannually remove it? I've tried to run some aggregation querys and it doesn't work. Also, the collection have more than 1.000.000 of documents.

Comment: How are you copying documents from one collection to another?

Comment: I'm using NoSqlManager and throws me that error. I can do it using mongoexport and mongoimport but i'd like to find that document to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two fields with same key in a collection in MongoDB.

Your error on the duplicate key is not caused by this situation, but certainly by a unique index on the arrival collection.

Comment: I was thinking that too, what you can have two fields with the same key in a document, but using Robo3T and a MongoDB DB  i'm able to edit a document and put two same keys in a document. (Uploading screenshot)

Comment: Here's the screenshot, Even, I was able to duplicate the _id field that has an index https://ibb.co/kKyzGTW

Comment: Are you sure that the names are different in all respects? ('email' is different from 'email   ')

Comment: Do you mean the value of both fields? I'm not sure if they are the same or not. :(